# Angular 6 and AngularFire2 RxJS Error

Tags: angularfire2

I want to create a new Angular 6 App with AngularFire 2.
Although I followed the tutorial, I get a version error.

AngularFire2 Setup Tutorial: 
https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/install-and-setup.md

Even though I only tried to use an Observable as seen in the tutorial I get the following error:

```
ERROR in node_modules/angularfire2/angularfire2.d.ts(3,10): error TS2305: Module '"/Users/tarek/Documents/Development/web_app/apphoven-web/node_modules/rxjs/Subscription"' has no exported member 'Subscription'.
node_modules/angularfire2/firestore/collection/changes.d.ts(3,10): error TS2305: Module '"/Users/tarek/Documents/Development/web_app/apphoven-web/node_modules/rxjs/Observable"' has no exported member 'Observable'.
node_modules/angularfire2/firestore/collection/collection.d.ts(3,10): error TS2305: Module '"/Users/tarek/Documents/Development/web_app/apphoven-web/node_modules/rxjs/Observable"' has no exported member 'Observable'.
node_modules/angularfire2/firestore/document/document.d.ts(3,10): error TS2305: Module '"/Users/tarek/Documents/Development/web_app/apphoven-web/node_modules/rxjs/Observable"' has no exported member 'Observable'.
node_modules/angularfire2/firestore/firestore.d.ts(3,10): error TS2305: Module '"/Users/tarek/Documents/Development/web_app/apphoven-web/node_modules/rxjs/Observable"' has no exported member 'Observable'.
node_modules/angularfire2/firestore/interfaces.d.ts(1,10): error TS2305: Module '"/Users/tarek/Documents/Development/web_app/apphoven-web/node_modules/rxjs/Subscriber"' has no exported member 'Subscriber'.
node_modules/angularfire2/firestore/observable/fromRef.d.ts(2,10): error TS2305: Module '"/Users/tarek/Documents/Development/web_app/apphoven-web/node_modules/rxjs/Observable"' has no exported member 'Observable'.
node_modules/rxjs/Observable.d.ts(1,15): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'rxjs-compat/Observable'.
node_modules/rxjs/Subscriber.d.ts(1,15): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'rxjs-compat/Subscriber'.
node_modules/rxjs/Subscription.d.ts(1,15): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'rxjs-compat/Subscription'.
```

Am I correct that AngularFire 2 does not support Angular 6? Because it's not written anywhere. And I don't think it's a good idea to downgrade to the old Angular CLI... So, what can I do?

Comment: did you  `npm install --save rxjs-compat` ? as far as i know firebase has yet to add changes to support angular 6, it was released just yesterday

Comment: Thanks ````npm install --save rxjs-compat ```` works for me

Answer (score 15, accepted):

now work with

```
npm install --save rxjs-compat
```

Answer (score 2):

Install the following file

```
npm install --save rxjs-compat
```

Comment: Seems like a repeat of [this existing answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50283410).

Answer (score 1):

Add following code in polyfills.ts
**(window as any).global = window;**

Answer (score 1):

npm install --save @rxjs-compat@5.0

Answer (score 1):

You've to fix your Rxjs imports. There are some changes in the use of rxjs from v6 onwards. so,
Kindly import the observable as below

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
```

instaed of `import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';`

Hope this will fix your issue. Happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

`npm i --save rxjs-compat` helps!

Comment: Explain also how your answer helps OP.